# Node.js timing w/ activedirectory package

Tags: javascript, node.js, active-directory

I'm quite a noob with Node but found that the **activedirectory** package is far better than any alternative Python module for extracting recursive group members across an AD forest so figured, right tool for the job. I've done loads with JS before but obviously this is a different kettle of fish.

Basically, I have the following:

```
var ad = new ActiveDirectory(config);

const groupName = 'CN=myGroupName*'
let group_members = []

ad.findGroups(groupName, function(err, groups) {
    groups.forEach(function(group) {
        ad.getUsersForGroup(group.dn, function(err, users) {
            users.forEach(function(user) {
                group_members.push([group.cn, user.sAMAccountName])
            })
        })
    })
})
```

The problem is that this works perfectly but the next thing I need to do is to put the result into a DB but I can't get the timing right. I've added this to test:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(group_members)
    return
}, 5000)
```

which works but it's obviously not ideal.

Unfortunately, I'm stuck with Node.js 6 (using AWS Lambda) so can't even use Promises AFAIK. Has anyone got any ideas how I'd do this properly?

Comment: You can use Promises with Node 6, even with Node 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to map your user array, to an array of Promises that resolves when one user was processed, so you can await all Promises to finish using Promise.all:

```
 const done = new Promise(res => {
   ad.findGroups(groupName, function(err, groups) {
     res(Promise.all(groups.map(function(group) {
        return new Promise(res => {
           ad.getUsersForGroup(group.dn, function(err, users) {
             users.forEach(function(user) {
             group_members.push([group.cn, user.sAMAccountName])
           });
           res();
        });
     })));
  });
});
```

So you can do:

```
 done.then(() => console.log(group_members));
```

---

Alternatively, you could promisify the API and use the new async/await syntax:

```
const {promisify} = require("util");
const findGroups = promisify(ad.findGroups);
const getUsersForGroups = promisify(ad.getUsersForGroups);

(async function(){
  const groupMembers = [];
  const groups = await findGroups(groupName);
  for(const group of groups){
    const users = await getUsersForGroups(group.dn);
    for(const user of users)
       groupMembers.push([group.cn, user.sAMAccountName]);
  }
  //all done
  console.log(groupMembers);
})()
```

(However this will proceed one request after another)

Comment: Thanks Jonas, really neat answer :) And learned some new tricks! Unfortunately async/await is Node 8 so can't use that but the first solution is perfect!

Comment: glad to help @allan :) i prefer the later one as it is much more beautiful imo, but if you cant update going with the first one is probably the way to go